# Entityframework Table name is appended with 'es' on savechanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm facing a strange error using entityframe work. I have model entity called "UserInfo" and my DB table name is also "UserInfo". However when i'm called the savechanges() in entity frame work. i'm getting a strange error like Invalid object name 'dbo.UserInfoes'.

I searched the entire solution, to see whether i miss typed anything to "UserInfoes" and i didnt find anything. Please help me to solve this issue. How "es" is append along with it?

```
[Table("UserInfo")]
public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    public string Field3 { get; set; }

    public string Field4 { get; set; }

    public int Field5 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the Pluralize Table Names for the LINQ to SQL designer.

Here is the steps
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384507.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is probably to do with settings. EF will pluralise table names automatically under some circumstances. The problem may be your entity name: `Userinfo -> Userinfoes`. It looks like you are using code first so look at your entity settings.